# "unexpected token 我" error with JSON in Mandarin

Tags: angularjs, json, internationalization

I have a JSON file with keys in English and values in Mandarin. When I try to get these values into a controller I get an "unexpected token error". Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

code:

```
getIntlTheme: function (param) {
                 return $http.get("INTL_JSON.json",{header:{'Content-Type':'application/json;charset:UTF-8'}})
                       .then(function (result) {
                              console.log(result)
                              return result.data;
                       });
          }
```

JSON:

{
"help" : "我"
}

Comment: can you show some code on which exactly the error occurs?

Comment: I had the same issue and it had to do with the source of the data (in my case, a JAVA servlet approaching a MySQL database). I fixed it by setting properly the encoding of the connection and the POST requests. Since you are not posting any code, this is all I can say about this. By the way, the issue is the added `"` that you can see after the mandarin symbol.

Comment: @CozyAzure added code and json

Comment: @maverick as far as I am concerned, properly stating the charset shouldn't be a problem. See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7DEscOVhEcHD0oCR1clv?p=preview). Are you sure the errors occurs at your `$http` function?

Comment: Yes, because I am not getting result from "console.log(result)"

Comment: The problem is with my JSON.It is not accepting only that mandarin symbol.After I deleted that it is working. Thank you for the quick response :)